# Double integral of the following Exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am interested in the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v_1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathop{\mathrm{d}v_2}v_1v_2\exp\left(-\frac{(v_1-v_2)^2}{2a}\right).$$
Does any one have any idea? My idea was to use the transformation $$v=v_1-v_2,\qquad v_+=\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}.$$
But I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral diverges.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathop{\mathrm{d}v_2}v_2\exp\left(-\frac{(v_1-v_2)^2}{2a}\right)=\sqrt{2 \pi a}\nu_1\ .
$$
Hence
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\nu_1 \nu_1 (\sqrt{2 \pi a}\nu_1) = \infty\ .
$$